# How to disable android snackbar opening animation from bottom screen

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, android-snackbar

I'm using CustomSnackBar library from GITHUB ,

Check this: https://github.com/TakeoffAndroid/CustomSnackBar/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/takeoffandroid/customsnackbar/SnackBar.java

This is so useful to customize my snackbar.

But I want to DISABLE snackbar opening animation , now its opening from bottom screen with some duration (Y- translation) .

**Is there any way to show snackbar without animation or disable the animation or reduce animation duration to 0(zero) ??**

- Android Studio ver:2.1
- compileSdkVersion 23
- buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
- Design Lib : com.android.support:design:23.3.0
  Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With current version (*design-24.1.0*), a simple fix doesn't look possible, but there's a way to hack it (see below)

Inside *Snackbar*, the *showView* method is invoked to display the snackbar

```
final void showView() {
    [...]

    if (ViewCompat.isLaidOut(mView)) {
        if (shouldAnimate()) {
            // If animations are enabled, animate it in
            animateViewIn();
        } else {
            // Else if anims are disabled just call back now
            onViewShown();
        }
    }

    [...]
}

private boolean shouldAnimate() {
        return !mAccessibilityManager.isEnabled();
}
```

*showView* is final so we can't do anything, plus we can't touch any of the code that determines if the snackbar should be animated.

Regarding the animation itself, the methods *animateViewIn* and *animateViewOut* are both private, and all of the code inside relies on private fields or constants

**Edit:**

What I do to simulate that there are no animations is handle *Snackbar*'s visibility

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

snackbar.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

[...]

snackbar.setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
      @Override
      public void onShown(Snackbar snackbar) {
        super.onShown(snackbar);

        snackbar.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
    });

snackbar.show();
```

And since in my case I control when the Snackbar is dimissed, I can do this

```
  snackbar.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);

  snackbar.dismiss();
```

Unfortunately, I don't think this last step is easy for non-indeterminate Snackbars. A way to hack this is to schedule a *setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)* at the duration of LENGTH_SHORT and LENGTH_LONG

In *SnackbarManager*. We can't access the constants, but we can copy&paste

```
private static final int SHORT_DURATION_MS = 1500;
private static final int LONG_DURATION_MS = 2750;
```

Then in your code, inside *Callback.onShown()*

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            snackbar.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          }
        }, LONG_DURATION_MS or SHORT_DURATION_MS)
```

I haven't tested this myself, maybe it should be called before onShown. If someone tries it, edit the post or let me know in the comments.

Comment: Good one. Maragues

Answer (score 1):

For kotlin user, you can try following code:

```
showError(message: String, viewGroup: ViewGroup) {

val duration: Long = 2000

val snackBar = Snackbar.make(viewGroup, message, duration.toInt())
snackBar.withColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, com.sdei.sdeiarchitecture.R.color.colorAccent))

val params = snackBar.view.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP
snackBar.view.layoutParams = params

val messageTv = snackBar.view.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text) as TextView
messageTv.textSize = 20.0f

snackBar.view.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
snackBar.addCallback(object : Snackbar.Callback() {
    override fun onShown(snackbar: Snackbar?) {
        super.onShown(snackbar)
        snackbar!!.view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        Handler().postDelayed({
            snackbar.view.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }, duration)
    }
})

snackBar.show()

}
```

Hope it will help you out.